# how do i insert a polygon point in mysql geometric column using codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, geolocation, polygon

what is wrong with my code?

> $this->db->query("update profile set polygon = POLYGON((0 0,82 33,23
>   66,0 0)) where id = 1");

polygon is a column with type of geometric(polygon).
i paste this "POLYGON((0 0,82 33,23 66,0 0))" in that column in phpmyadmin and it is saved but wuth query it in not work

Comment: what will POLYGON return can you show here? And Try to concatenate it in your query

Comment: @M.Hemant Query error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '0,82 33,23 66,0 0))

Comment: Do you need double (( )) - shouldn't it just be 1 of each?

Comment: @Antony i tried it with single parenteses but didnt worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
$this->db->query("update profile set polygon = ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0,82 33,23 66,0 0))') where id = 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - it uses Query Builder (part of Codeigniter) of which I am a fan!!

```
$this->db->set('polygon','POLYGON(0 0,82 33,23 66,0 0)',false);
$this->db->where('id',1);
$this->db->update('profile');
```

Note the `false` stops CI from quoting/escaping your query. Obviously if you accept user supplied information in there - then this would have to be checked for SQL injection elsewhere or this query amended.